# Change intermediate activations/output and observe prediction in TF2/Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

Let us say I have a simple NN model classifying MNIST like so:

```
model = models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
```

And I extract the output tensor from the 2nd layer, i.e. Dense layer (after activation relu) like so:

```
mid_layer = model.get_layer("dense")
get_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input], [mid_layer.output])
```

For some particular data input `x`, I extract the output tensor activation **values** now:

```
mid_layer_outputs = get_output([test_images[0:1]])
```

And make some changes to it:

```
mid_layer_outputs = ...
```

And now, I would like the model to continue from this layer's modified output values and predict results accordingly. How would I do that?

I tried to construct another `K.function([mid_layer_outputs], model.layers[-1].output)` starting from this layer to the end, but I got the following error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'op'

which is understandable as it cannot continue predictions with a NP array object instead of a model layer object. How do I do this?

Comment: You can create a custom Keras Layer to modify incoming tensors and pass to the next layer. See [here](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/#the-layer-class-the-combination-of-state-weights-and-some-computation).

Comment: Did you want add that change before or after the model is trained? if the former then check this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835778/feed-keras-model-input-to-the-output-layer/65855047#65855047), if is latter then just creating a custom layer and add after the 2nd layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - I need to specify the next layer inputs in the second `K.function` and then pass in the modified outputs to it:

```
get_pred = K.function([model.layers[2].input], model.layers[-1].output)
pred = get_pred([mid_layer_outputs])
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142181/whats-the-purpose-of-keras-backend-function) answer, `K.function` runs the computation graph we created in the code, taking input from the first parameter and extracting the number of outputs as per the layers mentioned. So `K.function([mid_layer_outputs], model.layers[-1].output)` was not working earlier because instead of passing the layer for `K.function` to work with and connect to the output, I was passing in the values directly.